# Training the same model with Keras Model API and TensorFlow Estimator API gives different accuracies

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I've been experimenting with TensorFlow's higher level APIs recently and got some strange results: when I train a seemingly exact same model with the same hyperparameters using Keras Model API and TensorFlow Estimator API, I get different results (using Keras leads to ~4% higher accuracy).

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import VarianceScaling
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Load CIFAR-10 dataset and normalize pixel values
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
X_train = np.array(X_train, dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=np.int32).reshape(-1)
X_test = np.array(X_test, dtype=np.float32)
y_test = np.array(y_test, dtype=np.int32).reshape(-1)
mean = X_train.mean(axis=(0, 1, 2), keepdims=True)
std = X_train.std(axis=(0, 1, 2), keepdims=True)
X_train = (X_train - mean) / std
X_test = (X_test - mean) / std
y_train_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_test_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)



# Define forward pass for a convolutional neural network.
# This function takes a batch of images as input and returns
# unscaled class scores (aka logits) from the last layer
def conv_net(X):
    initializer = VarianceScaling(scale=2.0)

    X = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(X)

    X = Dense(10)(X)

    return X



# For training this model I use Adam optimizer with learning_rate=1e-3

# Train the model for 10 epochs using keras.Model API
def keras_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

    scores = conv_net(inputs)
    outputs = Activation('softmax')(scores)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=3e-3), 
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model1 = keras_model()
model1.fit(X_train, y_train_one_hot, batch_size=128, epochs=10)
results1 = model1.evaluate(X_test, y_test_one_hot)
print(results1)
# The above usually gives 79-82% accuracy




# Now train the same model for 10 epochs using tf.estimator.Estimator API
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'X': X_train}, y=y_train, \
                                                    batch_size=128, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True)
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'X': X_test}, y=y_test, \
                                                   batch_size=128, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)


def tf_estimator(features, labels, mode, params):
    X = features['X']

    scores = conv_net(X)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={'scores': scores})

    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=scores, labels=labels)

    metrics = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=tf.argmax(scores, axis=-1))}

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params['lr'], epsilon=params['epsilon'])
    step = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=tf.reduce_mean(loss), train_op=step, eval_metric_ops=metrics)


model2 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=tf_estimator, params={'lr': 3e-3, 'epsilon': tf.keras.backend.epsilon()})
model2.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
results2 = model2.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)
print(results2)
# This usually gives 75-78% accuracy

print('Keras accuracy:', results1[1])
print('Estimator accuracy:', results2['accuracy'])
```

I've trained both models 30 times, for 10 epochs each time: mean accuracy of the model trained with Keras is 0.8035 and mean accuracy of the model trained with Estimator is 0.7631 (standard deviations are 0.0065 and 0.0072 respectively). Accuracy is significantly higher if I use Keras. My question is why is this happenning? Am I doing something wrong or missing some important parameters? The architecture of the model is the same in both cases and I'm using the same hyperparametrers (I've even set Adam's epsilon to the same value, although it doesn't really affect overall result), but the accuracies are significantly different.

I also wrote training loop using raw TensorFlow and got the same accuracy as with Estimator API (lower than I get with Keras). It made me think that the default value of some parameter in Keras is different from TensorFlow, but they all actually seem to be the same.

I have also tried other architectures and sometimes I got smaller difference in accuracies, but I wasn't able to find any particular layer type that causes the difference. It looks like if I use more shallow network the difference often becomes smaller. Not always, however. For example, the difference in accuracies is even slightly bigger with the following model:

```
def simple_conv_net(X):
    initializer = VarianceScaling(scale=2.0)

    X = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(10)(X)

    return X
```

Again, I've trained it for 10 epochs 30 times using Adam optimizer with 3e-3 learning rate. Mean accuracy with Keras is 0.6561 and mean accuracy with Estimator is 0.6101 (standard deviations are 0.0084 and 0.0111 respectively). What can be causing such a difference?